# Building Realm for Mac Catalyst fails: Realm.h not found

Tags: ios, realm, cocoapods, mac-catalyst

I have an iOS app, which I recently updated to support Mac Catalyst. For the Mac version I added a new target, which I also added to my Podfile with the subset of the same libraries, including Realm.

The app builds well for "My Mac", but when I want to archive it (build for release), it fails with the following error:

"Umbrella header 'Realm.h' not found"

I am not familiar with the problem, what could go wrong?

I tried the usual Derived Data deleting, etc, but nothing seems to help. Is this some kind of problem with the CocoaPods, my config, or with Realm?

Comment: That's a cocoapods issue. You need to be using 1.10.2. You can check your version with `pod --version`. That can be updated with `sudo gem install cocoapods` or `sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin` if the first option doesn't work. That update should be available shortly. There's a [git #7213](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/7213) as well.

Answer (score 3):

Due to CocoaPods not releasing 1.10.2 I have fixed the same issue in my project.

1. Remove Realm from your pod file
2. `pod install` in terminal to remove it fully
3. Install Swift Package Manager for (Xcode) - https://swiftpackageregistry.com/realm/realm-cocoa

This should allow you to get the project archived successfully.